# How do you set the message the Authorization Services displays on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In case you're not familiar with Authorization Services, I'm talking about this window:

[image: Authorization Services window]

At the top, in bolded text, is the line "GitHub is trying to install a new helper tool." Some applications, like Xcode, can change that message to other text to do other things. How do they do that? How does Authorization Services *know* you're installing a helper tool?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages displayed in an authorization dialog are defined in the configuration file `/etc/authorization`, and is chosen based on what rights are being requested.

Comment: In other words , you can't set it.

Comment: Correct. The messages are predefined for certain standard actions, and it just so happens that XCode makes use of a number of unusual actions (like "update developer documentation").